# Minimizing functions with parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but here we go: Why doesn't

```
Minimize[Abs[x] + y, x]
```

return anything, and how can I fix this? (11.0.1.0)

By contrast,

```
Minimize[Abs[x] + 1, x]
```

and

```
Minimize[Abs[x]^2 + y, x]
```

work just fine.

Comment: In Mma 11.1.1 `Minimize[Abs[x] + y, x]` returns `{y, {x -> 0}}`. Bug?

Comment: @rhermans Thanks. So possibly this is an already-fixed bug; which is annoying given this is a site installation and therefore slow to update.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixing" it?  Mathematica cannot solve all problems that can be solved.  This problem is very easy to do by hand, so there is no point to do it with Mathematica.  If someone comes up with a sequence of steps that does produce a result *for this problem* in Mathematica, chances are the same steps won't work for a more complex similar problem.  For this reason, I do not think that this is an appropriate question on StackExchange (but I'll refrain from voting to close).

Comment: @Sharkos No, I would absolutely not call this a bug. It is a lack of a feature in an earlier version. It is not reasonable to expect a CAS to solve *all* problems.  You'll notice that your problem is special because it can't be solved by finding zeros of the derivative.

Comment: (No earlier version between 10.0-11.0 can solve it.)

Comment: @Szabolcs In most contexts, people appreciate provision of Minimal Working Examples because it helps elucidate what is going on. I think it is reasonable here too. I agree this is not an *error* in Mathematica, but I believe it is an *oversight* that this is not solved (and not simply a *feature request*), and apparently one which is reasonable, since it has been addressed. Regardless, the purpose of the question was (a) to establish if I was missing something and a different function/option would help; or (b) if there was anything worth learning about the issue. And there was: v11.1 fixes it.

Comment: @Szabolcs A reasonable and useful answer to this question would be, for example, "Why: Because this version of Mathematica does not in any situation support minimization with non-differentiable functions containing symbolic parameters. How: By upgrading to v11.1, or manually simplifying the problem." -- assuming that the 'Why' part is correct of course. Extra useful would be an expert's knowledge of what would be within v11.1's capability vis-a-vis symbolic minimization with piecewise functions.

Comment: For real values, use `Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2]` to get a differentiable function.

Comment: Thanks, @BobHanlon! That brings it within Mathematica's ability, though it is very slow to minimize functions over 2 variables. For example: ``Minimize[Sqrt[x^2] + Sqrt[(a - x)^2] + 
   Sqrt[(a + x)^2], {x}] // Timing`` is about 350 times faster than
``Minimize[Sqrt[y^2] + Sqrt[x^2] + Sqrt[(a - x)^2] + 
   Sqrt[(a + x)^2], {x, y}] // Timing``. But probably there's nothing more to be done there.